# How to translate from GeoJSON to GeoDataFrame

Tags: python, geojson, geopandas, rasterio, geodataframe

I want to convert GeoJSON into a GeoDataFrame, but it doesn't work.

GeoJSON is stored in a dictionary variable.

If you know of a solution, I would like to know how to solve this problem.

This is my code.

```py
geojson={
    'type': 'Feature', 
    'properties': {'name': 'building'}, 
    'geometry': {
        'type': 'Polygon', 
        'coordinates': [
            [
                 [139.288478, 36.50807], 
                 [139.288478, 36.508312], 
                 [139.288778, 36.508312], 
                 [139.288778, 36.50807], 
                 [139.288478, 36.50807]
            ]
        ]
    }
}


gdf=geopandas.GeoDataFrame(geojson,geometry='geometry',crs="EPSG:4326")
```

but

> `TypeError: Input must be valid geometry objects: Polygon`

I don't understand why Polygon is not a valid geometry object.

Comment: Take a look at these two very similar SE questions and their answers. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/343725/convert-geojson-to-geopandas-geodataframe and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37728540/create-a-geodataframe-from-a-geojson-object

Comment: Thanks for answer @ycartwhelen. Based on the site you taught me,  I converted it to shapely and then to geodataframe, and it worked! Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for answer @Vince. Based on the site you taught me,  I converted it to shapely and then to geodataframe, and it worked! Thank you.